Laravel Foreach in Foreach Loop (Loop Design)
I am making a registration system with reference. Everything works fine so far, but there's a point I'm stuck on.
First of all, anyone who is a member can invite someone. The person who accepts the invitation can register with the reference code of the person who sent the invitation.
However, there is such a situation in the system. Person A invited person B, person B invited person C. There are three people in the system.
When person A enters the panel, she should be able to see people B and C in the guest list.
This list will go on and on, the more foreach loops I add to the foreach loop, the more people in the lower row I can reach. How can I design this loop until I get to the last person?

My example foreach loop:
@php $leg = \App\Model\Reference::where(['user_id' => $reference->worker_id])->get(); @endphp

@foreach($leg as $user)
   {{ $user->user->name }}

   @php $leg = \App\Model\Reference::where(['user_id' => $user->worker_id])->get(); @endphp

   @foreach($leg as $user)
      {{ $user->user->name }}
   @endforeach
@endforeach

Since the records are cross-linked to each other, I don't know how to design a loop and how to display information about how many people have been invited via one person at a time.

What your current code display?

You probably don't have a huge list of users, so you could just fetch the whole Reference table in a single query and build the so-called "transitive closure" in the controller (not in the view). And beware of cycles.

Alternatively, you can use a recursive CTE query (as shown here).

It seems that by definition, cycles are impossible, right ?

@OrenIshShalom If A invites B, B invites C, and C invites A, you get a cycle. Maybe the system prevents that, but we don't know.

Recursion is going to be your friend here

I'm currently using a single foreach loop. I am person A. And since two people registered with reference code A, two people appear. No problems so far. When people who register to the system with my reference code invite others, I need to see them in the list. But I can't achieve this in a single loop.
